# VB6 Package and Deployment Wizard DLL Self Register SQL DMO Setup

Tags: vb6, sql-server-2000

I Want to install the SQLDMO along with my VB6 Application.. SQLDMO Client is used in my application for Database Backup..

Whenever the setup is installed in the target machine Win XP and While taking Backup There was an Error

`ActiveX Component Can't Create Object`

Here is my Code for Taking backup..

`Dim oSQLServer as new SQLDMO.SQLServer`

After the Successful Connection,

`Dim oBackup as New SQLDMO.Backup`

```
oBackup.Devices = nBack_Dev
oBackup.Database = nDB_Name
oBackup.BackupSetName = nBack_Set
oBackup.BackupSetDescription = nBack_Desc
oBackup.SQLBackup oSQLServer
oSQLServer.Disconnect
```

I had Created the Setup of my project using vb6 Package and Deployment Wizard but, I googled about SQLDMO manual installation and the Regarding Files must be self registered on the target machine..

how to do all these within the package and deployment wizard itself..

SQL-DMO includes the following files

- Sqldmo.dll : DLL that implements SQL-DMO objects
- Sqldmo.rll : DMO resource file
- Sqlresld.dll : SQL Enterprise Manager resource DLL loader
- Sqlsvc.dll : Database service layer
- Sqlsvc.rll : Database service layer resource DLL
- Sqlunirl.dll : SQL Server Unicode/ANSI translation layer
- W95scm.dll : SQL Service Control Manager abstraction layer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you may be missing:

```
sqlsrv32.dll: system32 folder 
sqlsrv32.rll: system32 folder
```

I've also found in the past that if the user was missing `msvcr71.dll` in the `system32` folder, the install would fail, but only copy if it doesn't exist.

FYI, the rest of the files should go into:

```
sqldmo.dll: %PROGRAM_FILES%\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn
sqldmo.rll: %PROGRAM_FILES%\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn\Resources\1033
sqlresld.dll: %PROGRAM_FILES%\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn
sqlsvc.dll: %PROGRAM_FILES%\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn
sqlsvc.rll: %PROGRAM_FILES%\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn\Resources\1033
sqlunirl.dll: system32 folder
w95scm.dll: %PROGRAM_FILES%\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn
```

Comment: Whether we should create MS SQL Server Folder in program files manually ?? and store the files???? Yea let me try.. this... thank you...

Comment: and one more question ! whether all the dll files (ActiveX Components) will be automatically registered in the target system???

Comment: @gokul-e: Yes, if the folders don't exist, you need to create them. It looks like only sqldmo.dll is self-registering.  I can't tell you how to do it with the VB Package and Destroy thing--no one should be using that disaster.  You'll have to look at the help to figure out how to mark sqldmo.dll so it will register on the user's machine.